# What avenues of science are left to explore for a scientist in the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, science

I know this question may be considered too broad, but I legitimately wonder what science scientists are working on in *Star Wars*. Many many people have said that there is no scientific progression in *Star Wars*; but I don’t believe that. Scientist characters are featured in stories and surely they must be doing something! That something is never revealed but I can’t help but speculate. I think they probably know what dark matter and dark energy are since Starkiller Base is powered by it. They probably know what the full size of the universe is, how it started, how it will end and why their is more matter than anti-matter.

They obviously know the origin of consciousness and how to create it since they have “sentient” droids.

That being said, what is left to wonder about?

Answer (score 2):

Xenoarchaeology and xenobiology would still be important fields of study among any spacefaring culture. Learning about newly discovered, or long extinct,creatures and civilizations, the same way we do in the real world. Finding better methods of propulsion or improving other forms of currently-existing technology would be invaluable as well. And even among a technologically-advanced setting like Star Wars, there's still plenty to learn about when it comes to stellar phenomena and newly charted planets and even mundane things like earthquakes and geological records on planets that have been inhabited for millennia.

In the real world, we've inhabited this Earth for thousands of years and we still learn and study new things every single day when it comes to the sciences. Take that and multiply it by a billionfold and you'll find that in an entire *galaxy*, especially one that has a segment literally called the *Unknown Regions*, there would likely be thousands, hundreds of thousands, of scientific studies, discoveries, and breakthroughs.